# Leaving XMPP Room Permanently As a Member

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, xmppframework

We're implementing an xmpp client and we are using ejabberd as xmpp server.
We've implemented muc (multi user chat) functionalities to our app and everything is working fine , only thing we are having problem is  a member to leave the group permanently.

I know in XEP 45 says if you want to leave the group just send the unavailable presence to room but this doesnt work in our case because our admins add users of the group to memberList
by sending the below xml:

```
<iq from='crone1@shakespeare.lit/desktop'
    id='member1'
    to='coven@chat.shakespeare.lit'
    type='set'>
  <query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#admin'>
    <item affiliation='member'
          jid='hag66@shakespeare.lit'
          nick='thirdwitch'/>
  </query>
</iq>
```

And when a member send unavailable presence, this doesnt affect the groups member list(Which is working as we wanted)
So we want to find a way for a member to remove himself/herself from group members list permanently so he/she wont be able to receive any messages from that group anymore
Is something like that possible? Can we remove ourself from groups member's list like whatsapp's leave chat functionality.

Answer (score 0):

When user leaves room he will not receive messages anymore - XMPP MUCs are presence-based. "Member lists" are only for administrative purposes and does not control message receiving.

There are some another XMPP extension specifications designed with "persistent" member list in mind, for example [MUC Light](https://xmpp.org/extensions/inbox/muc-light.html) - it can be more suited for you needs.

Comment: I know the member list are not related with message receiving but the problem here is , in our xmpp client application: members of the group also checks the member list to see who else in the room. So if the person who ise leaving the room doesnt remove himself/herself from the group's members list. Other members will always see him as a participant. I want to fix that problem.
It works fine when an admin remove a member(or ban a member) but it doesnt work  when the member try to remove himself

Comment: Your client application doing unusual things as trying to emulate "persistent" member list on top of "presence-based" XMPP MUC, while managing member list still allowed only for moderators. If you want to continue to do this, you need explicitly allow usual members to edit member list, which may require to edit code of your xmpp server.

Comment: I quote Vitalyster. You have just a solution: add a custom Extension Element to your "leave" action and let Ejabber remove the subscription server side. Client side a member can't remove it's own membership. However with persistant member list emulated by role-list, avoid to user members at all, members have scope restrictions about that porpouse

Comment: @MrPk Can you explain a little bit about what you are saying:  
`add a custom Extension Element to your "leave" action and let Ejabber remove the subscription server side`.
Which element should I have to add for ejabberd to understand leave and remove the subscription?

Comment: You have to implement yourself. Xmpp supports Extension Element, that means custom tags to trigger events. So while you send a leave command that looks like <presence>foo</presence> you can attach a nested tag like <presence><removeasmember/></presence>. With this, server side, you can remove member subscription by database or as superadmin. You have to implement the full functionality by yourself becaouse it's off XMPP

Comment: @tolgatanriverdi you can extend XMPP elements with any required child element (not forget to create elements in your own XML namespace!) and put any logic on client and server sides. There is no "standard" element for that in ejabberd, you should add an extension to ejabberd too

Comment: Do you know any documentation to implement custom tags in ejabberd side with erlang?

Answer (score 0):

As defined in XEP-0045, if the MUC admin added another user as member, that added user cannot remove himself as member.
However, as a default in XEP-0045, MUC members do not receive message. This brings me to think this is not the problem you are hitting.

I suggest that you use MUC/Sub as implemented in ejabberd and defined in this specification for more flexibility. It is 100% compliant with MUC specification, so MUC compliant client and MUC/Sub enhanced client can participate in the same workflow.

In your case, I think that you need to subscribe your users to the events he wants (message, possibly presence or configuration changes). Subscription can be handled by users so that user can also control unsubscribe. It should do exactly what you want.

You need ejabberd 16.09 to use that specification. MUC/Sub is defined here: https://docs.ejabberd.im/developer/xmpp-clients-bots/proposed-extensions/muc-sub/